# speed up data import to sql from windows forms

Tags: sql-server, winforms, io

I've made a windows forms app that imports data to my sql database.

This is how data can look in the database

[image]

**Problem** If I now want to import more data and say that there is a entry in the new data that I'm importing that already exist in my sql data table, that is, an entry with the exact same value that already exist in my sql table. Then I would like to not import this particular entry and move on the next one.

The code I'm using for this is paintstakingly slow and I would like to find a quicker/better way of doing this. Please see #region DAX for the code and the try catch.

Here is the code that executes on my button click for import :) 
Thanks!

```
 private void dataImportButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;

        int candle = 0;
        string candleStick = "";
        foreach (var item in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
        {
            candleStick += item.ToString();
        }
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"\d*");
        Match match = regex.Match(candleStick);
        if (match.Success)
        {
            candle = Convert.ToInt32(match.Value);
        }


        string nameOfTable = string.Empty;
        foreach (var item in checkedListBox2.CheckedItems)
        {
            nameOfTable += item.ToString();
        }


        string filePath = textBox1.Text;
        var listaNerladdat = System.IO.File.ReadLines(filePath);


        if (nameOfTable == "DAX")
        #region DAX
        {



            foreach (var item in listaNerladdat)
            {
                var splitLista = item.Split(';').ToList();

                if (splitLista.Count < 5)
                    continue;

                var tmpSplitInfo = new DaxSuperTabell();


                DateTime tmpDate;
                if (DateTime.TryParse(splitLista[0], out tmpDate))
                    tmpSplitInfo.TimeStampMVCR = tmpDate;

                double tmpX;
                if (Double.TryParse(splitLista[1].Replace('.', ','), out tmpX))
                    tmpSplitInfo.HighPriceMVCR = tmpX;


                if (Double.TryParse(splitLista[2].Replace('.', ','), out tmpX))
                    tmpSplitInfo.LowPriceMVCR = tmpX;

                if (Double.TryParse(splitLista[3].Replace('.', ','), out tmpX))
                    tmpSplitInfo.OpenPriceMVCR = tmpX;

                if (Double.TryParse(splitLista[4].Replace('.', ','), out tmpX))
                    tmpSplitInfo.ClosePriceMVCR = tmpX;

                tmpSplitInfo.CandleStick = candle;


                try{
                _context.DaxSuperTabell.AddRange(tmpSplitInfo);
                _context.SaveChanges();
                    }
                catch{MessageBox.Show("This entry is a double")}                                      

            }                     

        }
        #endregion

    }
```

Comment: one thing you can do is NOT create and declare objects and variables inside the loop, but before you start the loop. Also try..catch is not fast try to avoid that inside a loop

Comment: Reason for the try catch in the loop is because I only want the particular entry that is a doublette (spelling) to not be saved to context. 

If I do the add and save context outside the loop the whole import of every entry does not work to add. 

Not sure how to get around this issue.

Comment: I dont know what exceptions can happen here, but maybe there are other ways to check for that condition ? But you can start by moving every declaration and ever `object creation` out of the loop. The `new`keyword can significant slow down loops. Declaring variables also can slow down loops. Better is to declare/create them before the loop starts and reuse them inside the loop